# Serde-yaml list of structs

Tags: rust, serde

I've got some yaml like this

```
---
include:
    - something.yaml

vlans:
    office:
        vid: 100
        description: "office network"
        acls_in: [office-vlan-protect]
        faucet_mac: "0e:00:00:00:10:01"
        faucet_vips:
            - '10.0.100.254/24'
            - '2001:100::1/64'
            - 'fe80::c00:00ff:fe00:1001/64'
        routes:
            - route:
                  ip_dst: '192.168.0.0/24'
                  ip_gw: '10.0.100.2'
    guest:
        vid: 200
        description: "guest network"
        faucet_mac: "0e:00:00:00:20:01"
        faucet_vips:
            - '10.0.200.254/24'
            - '2001:200::1/64'
            - 'fe80::c00:00ff:fe00:2001/64'
```

and I'm trying to deserialize it into these structs

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Route {
    ip_dst : String,
    ip_gw : String,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct VLAN {
    vid : u16,
    description : String,
    #[serde(default)]
    acls_in : Vec<String>,
    faucet_mac : String,
    faucet_vips : Vec<String>,
    #[serde(default)]
    routes : Vec<Route>
    }



#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Document {
    include: Vec<String>,
    vlans: HashMap<String,VLAN>,
}
```

My problem is with the routes. `Err` value:

> Message("missing field `ip_dst`", Some(Pos { marker: Marker { index:
> 346, line: 16, col: 19 }, path: "vlans.office.routes[0]" }))

Why can't it find `ip_dst` in the yaml file? I can change the struct if I need to but the yaml can't be changed.

Comment: If I do this ```#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Route {
    route: HashMap<String,String>
}``` I get a hashmap with ip_dst and ip_gw keys and values but I'd prefer to be able to dot into the values.

Comment: Your structure has a mismatch. The YAML has `routes` as an array of single-key maps, where `route` is the name of that key. Your serde structure doesn't account for the fact that there's a `route` key containing the map that you want.